How do I know if my neck is hypermobile? What is its normal range of movement?
Question: How do I know if my neck is hypermobile?
A buddy of mine states their neck as hypermobile but I don't think so. That or both of ours might be. How can we check?
Edit:
To show prior research, this link is appended:

https://physicaltherapyoregon.com/2018/03/22/7-signs-you-may-have-hypermobility/

As shown in the link, many websites include generalized descriptions of hypermobility instead of a specialized resource to a certain region.
There are some guides to helping see if you have restricted movement of the neck.

Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Your source is a generalized description of hypermobility as seen in, e.g. Ehlers-Danlos. Your question is about the neck specifically. Pertinent research would address hypermobility of the neck specifically. There's plenty of literature on (joint) ranges of motion - including the neck - which doesn't amount to an advertisement for a physical therapist. Please try again, specifically concentrating on the neck. Thanks.
